# How to respond to onChange event for a dropdown in angularify

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, onchange

I'm trying to use angularify in a project, but I'm facing the given problem:

I'm not able to get my onChange function called when a dropdown value changes. I have a second dropdown box which the listed values depends upon the first one.

How can I achieve the intended behavior with angularify?

I was looking, debugging and trying, and looks like I will not be able to do this because de dropdown directive writes a bunch of div's to my html. There is no select elmeent in any place of the document. How will a div element fire a onChange event?

Here is my markup:

## Parent select

```
<dropdown title="Selecione" class="col-6" ng-model="novoProcedimento.procedimento" ng-change="buscarLocaisExecucao(novoProcedimento.procedimento)">
  <dropdown-group class="meudropdown"  title="proc.nome" value="proc.nome" ng-repeat="proc in procedimentosPermitidos">{{proc.nome}}</dropdown-group>
</dropdown>
```

## Child select - Depends on parent's selection

```
<dropdown title="Selecione" id="dente-regiao" class="col-5" ng-model="novoProcedimento.local" ng-change="buscarFaces(novoProcedimento.procedimento, novoProcedimento.local)">
  <dropdown-group title="local" value="local" ng-repeat="local in locaisExecucao">{{local.descricao}}</dropdown-group>
</dropdown>
```

## Controller - Intendend to be fired on parent's change.

```
$scope.buscarLocaisExecucao = function (procedimento){
  selecaoProcedimentoService.buscarLocaisExecucao(procedimento)
   .then(function(locaisExecucao) {
     $scope.locaisExecucao = locaisExecucao;
   });
}
```

Am I using the wrong framework? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: File a [GitHub Angularify New Issue](https://github.com/angularify/angular-semantic-ui/issues/new). Their directive doesn't support `ng-change`. Their directive uses isolate scope and AngularJS `ng-change` assumes inherited scope.

Comment: @georgeawg, do you think it's "just" a matter scopes? Once I didn't see any select object either in the source code or in directives templates, it looks like this framework is unable to fire change events. The framework uses a lot of div's to render the select box.. I'm starting to think that a should pick another framework.

Am I wrong?

Comment: There are more problems than that. They don't link to the `ngModelController` and `ng-change` uses `ngModelController`. Instead of trying to fix their buggy code, would it be easier to use [angular-ui dropdown](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)?

Comment: Nice. I will take a look and consider use bootstrap. Thank you